# Efficient histogram on multiple columns in one shot

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here's how I calculate histogram on one column:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/project/test.csv")
df.map(row => row.getString(2).toDouble).rdd.histogram(10)
```

I want to calculate histograms on all columns. I can simply repeat the second line (see code above) and call histogram separately on each column. But my concern is that Spark will load data from disk each time I call histogram(), which means that if there are 10 columns, data is loaded 10 times. Is there a more efficient way to do this? How can I calculate histograms on all 10 columns in one shot?

**Edit**

Here's one way to combine multiple histogram() calls into one expression:

```
val histograms = {
  val a = df.map(row => row.getString(0).toDouble).rdd.histogram(10)
  val b = df.map(row => row.getString(1).toDouble).rdd.histogram(15)
  (a, b)
}
```

Does this guarantee that the histograms will be computed with only one pass over the data? Is combining multiple histogram calls into one expression the trick? Or is that even necessary? Doesn't Spark delay evaluation until the result is used in any case, even when separate statements are used?

Comment: @eliasah I have clarified the question. Essentially the question is, is it necessary to combine multiple actions into a single expression for those actions to be computed in a single pass? Or does Spark do that for you even with multiple separate statements, as long as you don't use the results till all statements are executed?

Comment: To avoid loading the data every time, you can `persist` the RDD